# Login failed for user '' IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

Im currently trying to deploy my .NET MVC Application to IIS 7.5.
There is a database connection problem that im trying to figure out. In localhost, everything seems fine, however, when I deploy my app to remote server, the app runs, without connecting to database. For example I have a VisualLeadController that has getMonthlyLeadsByYear() method that connects to database and retyrns data. When I try to execute it from brower by typing

http://staging2.landornet.com/WebLeadsVisualizer/VisualLead/getMonthlyLeadsByYear

It generates this error:

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ''.

The steps that I followed:

1-Removed integrated security=True from WebConfig connection strings
2- Changed applicationpool identity from applicationPoolIdentity to local system.

Still now working... anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When deploying your web app to your remote server, you will need to use a SQL connection string that contains an explicit username and password associated with a SQL account.  For example,

```
Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;User ID=SQLUSERNAME;Password=SQLUSERPASSWORD
```

To use this connection string, you will need to first use SQL Management Studio to create a SQL login with a username and password, and give that user access to your database.  Then log out out of SQL Management Studio and log back in using that user/password to make sure that it correctly can access your database.  Hopefully then your web app should be able to connect to the database.

Comment: I did. I added a new connection string with credentials and tested connection successfully! Im experiencing this problem after all those steps.